# Whats the closest thing to Web Deploy for .net on linux?

Tags: .net, linux

I want to get back into .net programming but I dont want to use Windows Server. One thing I used to love about Windows Server/.net is the simplicity of Web Deploy. For .net on linux, how can I upload/refresh a .net app in one click?

Comment: If you read a little bit about containers, you will see why Web Deploy (private protocol, Windows only) is not very useful nowadays wherever containers (open standard) are supported.

Comment: I dont care for or want to use containers. Thank you though.